# Find if key or value exist in the array's nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

I have an array of nested objects.

```
const data = [
  {
    audi: {
      model_Q3: 'Q3',
      model_A3: 'A3'
    }
  },
  {
    mercedes: {
      model_GLA: 'GLA',
      model_GLC: 'GLC'
    }
  }
];
```

I want a function to return true if the nested object's (audi, mercedes) key or value equals/includes the parameter.

```
function findCar(parameter) {
  let exists = false;
  data.forEach(cars => {
    Object.entries(cars).map(([_, carValues]) => {
        console.log(carValues)
    });
  }); 
}

findCar('model_Q3') //true;
findCar('model_') //true;
findCar('GLA') // true;
findCar('GL') // true;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with a simple object the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method should come quite handy here. It constructs a json string that contains the entire object, and therefore all the keys and values you have in your object. With that string you can extract every key or value by a regex match.

This is how it may look like:

```
function findCar(parameter) {
    const keysAndValues = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"([^"]+)"/g);
    for (let entry of keysAndValues) if (entry.includes(parameter)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

The regex here matches for every entry that starts with ", then only characters that are not " and followed by a ".

Comment: Thank you very much.